# Simplify RegEx: Avoid both test and replace

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need a function in PHP and JavaScript that adds a parenthesised year to a title. But if the title contains a parenthesised word, the year and word should share the parenthesis, separated by "/".

```
foo("Ferrari (ABC)", 2016); // Ferrari (2016/ABC)
foo("Ferrari", 1979);       // Ferrari (1979)
foo("X(Y)Z (PQR)", 1987);   // X(Y)Z (1987/PQR)
```

Currently, I check for a pattern, replace if there is a match, and do something else if not. Can this function be reduced to a simpler (preferably single) operation? Please supply a complete example.

PHP:

```
function foo($title, $year) {
  $pattern = "/(\()([A-Z]+\))$/";
  if(preg_match($pattern, $title))
    $title = preg_replace($pattern, "${1}".$year."/${2}", $title);
  else
    $title = "$title ($year)";
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function foo(title, year) {
  var pattern = /(\()([A-Z]+\))$/;
  if(pattern.test(title))
    title = title.replace(pattern, "$1"+year+"/$2");
  else
    title = title + " (" + year + ")";
}
```

Comment: use `indexOf('(')`?

Comment: are you looking for speed? or are you looking for less bytes of code?

Comment: Less bytes of code. Or mostly to get rid of the if/else. But not at the cost of an overly complex RegEx. Just if there's a simple, brilliant way I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a much simpler aproach.

1- check if you have a parenthesis inside $title.
If TRUE, just do a simple search/replace with the function [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).  Search for `"("` replace with  `"($yaer/"`
This will just add the year and the slash to the string you all ready have.

2- If you don't have parenthesis, then just `$title = "$title ($year)";`

```
function foo($title, $year) {
 if ( strpos($title,"(") > 1 )
   $title = str_replace("(","($year/",$title);
 else
   $title = "$title ($year)";
}
```

Same logic goes for Javascript

Comment: The main part of title can contain parenthesis too, so only a trailing parenthesis containing a single, uppercase word should be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Using replace would, arguably, be a little easier.

**PHP**

```
<?php

function foo($title, $year) {
    if (substr($title,-1) == ")") {
        return str_replace(")","/".$year.")",$title);
    } else {
        return $title . " (" . $year . ")";
    }
}

echo foo("My Title (ABC)", 1996);
echo "<br />";
echo foo("My Title", 1996);

?>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function foo(title, year) {
 if (title.charAt(title.length - 1) == ")")
  return title.replace(")",  "/" + year + ")");
 else
  return title + " (" + year + ")";
}

console.log(foo("My Title (ABC)",1996));
console.log(foo("My Title",1996));
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The year should come *before* the word. Other than that it's a nice a simplification, however, I was hoping there was a way that did not involve if/else.

Answer (score 0):

Example with using RegExp in Javascript:

```
  function foo(str, year) {
    var re = /(\(([A-Z]+)\))?$/
    return str.replace(re, function(b, b, found) {
      if (found) 
        return '(' + year + '/' + found + ')';
      else 
        return ' ' + year;
    })
  }
```